# difference between max3387ecug+ and max3387ecug+t

Tags: transceiver

can I know what the difference is between MAX3387ECUG+ and MAX3387ECUG+T, the MAXIM datasheet doesn't seem to point the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> T, T&R, T10 | Part is furnished on tape-and-reel. T or T&R indicates the standard reel quantity for the given package, usually 2.5K. T10 indicates a reel quantity of 10K.

[source](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/packaging/package-information/maxim-naming-conventions.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you see a "T" suffix on a part number, it's very likely indicating the part being sold in tape & reel packaging, and that does indeed seem to be the case here:

[image]